# Eigenvalue in the Energy Derivation from Klein-Gordon Equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, mass-energy, klein-gordon-equation

I was watching this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liQoSIaYBJk&list=PLXS_wzQAoIt7GxSRwCaicaSdeKqzYSUq4) for the derivation of Energy (chapter 3) from the Klein-Gordon equation where they had taken the two equations of $$(P^\mu  P_\mu-m^2)\psi=0$$ and $$(-(K^0)^2+\textbf{K}^{2}+m^2)\psi=0$$ which were derived from the einstein energy equation. Equating both leads to the equation $$(-(K ^{0})^{2}+\ \textbf{K}^{2}+m^2)\psi=(E^2-\textbf{P}^2-m^2)\psi\tag{1}$$ from
Now here the video says that the LHS is taken as the eigenvalue and the $(K^0)^2$ is the eigen value of $E ^2$ from RHS acting on $\psi$. And from this we get the relation that $-E^2+\textbf{K}^2+m^2=0$ which leads to the energy relation $$E=\mp(\textbf{K}^2+m^2)^{1/2}$$

Doubt: How can we say that the LHS is the eigenvalue and not the operator? Although the energy relation is correct but I'm not understanding why the LHS in equation (1) is treated as the eigenvalue and not as the operator while the RHS is being treated as the operator.

From what I understand in the RHS the term of $E^2-\textbf{P}^2$ comes from the relation of $P^{\mu}P_{\mu}= E^2-\textbf{P} ^2$ since the 4-vector $P_{\mu}=(E,\textbf{P_1},\textbf{P_2},\textbf{P_3})$ in natural units. So here the E is a vector component but when it is squared in the above equation ($E^2-\textbf{P}^2$) why is it treated as a operator?

Answer (score 0):

I think the author's notation is confusing you. It would have helped if they had put hats on the operators to make clear what are operators and what are eigenvalues. In the above case it is that $E^2$ is an operator on the RHS and could have been notated: $\hat {E^2}$. On the LHS you should understand ${K^0}^2 = E^2 $, where $E^2$ is the eigenvalue of the operator $\hat {E^2}$. If you do this there is no confusion. You might choose a different source for learning about the KG equation, like Peskin and Schroeder or Goldstein 3rd ed. It doesn't seem like the stuff you are showing is the most pedagogical, but...